# How can I compare two XMLs and display the differing line separately?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, xmldocument, xmldiff

I need to compare 2 XMLs and display the differing lines. I saw Microsoft XMLDiff and Patch. But I don't understand how to use it. How can I use it for two XMLs which are in the folloing format? I saw similar questions.But their elements are all in one format. Please help.

```
<ABC ID="" FID="123" CD="" EF="">
    <SCHOOL NAME="TEST" CLASS="TESTCLASS">
    <SUBJECT NAME="MATHS" VALUE="M1"/>
    <KICK AGE="21" VALUE="2"/>
    </SCHOOL>
</ABC>
```

Comment: Could you explain more about _how_ you need to do it?  Are you writing a C# program to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows I use a utility called WinMerge which is OpenSource and highly useful. It allows you to compare entire directory structures in addition to "Diff" ing two separate files.  There are also portable versions of it available so that you can put it on a USB Thumb Drive (or in dropbox) and run it from any PC which I find useful.  Highly recommended for anyone who does any form of programming!

[WinMerge Download](http://winmerge.org/downloads/)

Comment: How do I use WinMerge?

Comment: @Linus he needs to do this programmatically...not through tools

Comment: @user3727988  As mayooran mentions,  winmerge is just a tool to compare two xml files and it won't help you if you are attempting to do this diff dynamically within a program.   I wasn't sure that is what you were trying to do hence my comment.